# Script to run on logout per user in mac/Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm looking for a way to setup a list of script that run when I log out.
Basically, I want to write a server shutdown scripts for myself that will run automatically when a user log out or shut down per user logon. Able to start the server on logon via launchd. And how to shutdown server on logout.....

Env: Macbook pro 2010
OS version : OS X Version 10.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link says  that we cannot use logout script anymore :(

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CustomLogin.html